# Strunk For Mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, article-writing

Is anyone aware of a definitive ***published*** book for mathematical writing similar to Strunk's - "Elements of Style"? Inevitability almost all good math has to be communicated and written language is how that gets done. But I am not aware of a classic reference specifically for mathematicians? Presumably good mathematical writing should follow writing models similar to other scientific disciplines?

This question is not about good "LaTeX" writing or scripting for journal submission - that may vary by journal.

Comment: E.g. Krantz's Primer of mathematical writing. I'm sure it's not similar to the Elements of Style, though. Krantz has infinitely more sense of good language and writing.

Comment: You might also have a look at "How to write mathematics" by Paul Halmos [Enseignement Math. vol.16 (1970) 123–152].

Comment: I used Strunk as reference point. Technically Strunk & White.